# thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) with pcap_next

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, pcap

I'm trying to use `pcap_next` but my program stops on this line:

```
packet = pcap_next([self pcap_socket], hdr);
```

with the error:

```
thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

here is my code:

```
-(const u_char*)readOnPcapDescriptor
{
    if([self pcap_is_open]) {
        struct pcap_pkthdr *hdr = NULL;
        const u_char *packet;

        // read for the next packet
        packet = pcap_next([self pcap_socket], hdr);

        if(packet==NULL)
            return NULL;
        else
            return packet;
    }

    printf("NOK\nOpen descriptor First!\n\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

I don't understand where is my error here. The pcap_t descriptor is open before with this :

```
pcap_t * open_socket = pcap_open_live(if_name,BUFSIZ,1,1,pcap_errbuf);
```

And affected to an instance variable:

```
[self setPcap_socket:open_socket];
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `pcap_open_live` actually returned non-NULL?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the pcap descriptor to send a packet with pcap_inject before to start the reading with pcap_next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pcap_next documentation](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_next_ex.3pcap.html) does not say that the `pcap_pkthdr` argument is allowed to be NULL. Try passing a valid pointer to a `pcap_pkthdr` struct:

```
struct pcap_pkthdr hdr = {0};
packet = pcap_next([self pcap_socket], &hdr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `pcap_next()` tells you that "The pcap_pkthdr structure pointed to by h is filled in with the appropriate values for the packet."

That `h` is called `hdr` in your example, and you initialize it like this:

```
struct pcap_pkthdr *hdr = NULL;
```

In other words, `pcap_next()` tries to access the address at `NULL`, which is exactly what is stated in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> I can only read 2 packets

To quote the `pcap_next()` man page:

```
   pcap_next() returns a pointer  to  the  packet  data  on  success,  and
   returns  NULL  if  an  error occured, or if no packets were read from a
   live capture (if, for example, they were discarded because they  didn't
   pass the packet filter, or if, on platforms that support a read timeout
   that starts before any packets arrive, the timeout expires  before  any
   packets  arrive, or if the file descriptor for the capture device is in
   non-blocking mode and no packets were available to be read), or  if  no
   more  packets are available in a ``savefile.''  Unfortunately, there is
   no way to determine whether an error occured or not.
```

The important thing here is "and returns NULL if ... or if no packets were read from a live capture (...or if, on platforms that support a read timeout that starts before any packets arrive, the timeout expires before any packets arrive ..."

BSD-flavored OSes, such as OS X and iOS, support a read timeout that starts before any packets arrive, so you may get NULL returned if there aren't any packets *right now*.  That does *not* mean that there will *never* be any packets; you have to keep looping.

`pcap_next()` does not distinguish between errors and timeouts; as the man page says, "Unfortunately, there is no way to determine whether an error occured or not.".  Therefore, it is not, and has never been, a very good routine to use.

If you don't want to use routines that take callbacks, such as `pcap_dispatch()` or `pcap_loop()`, I suggest you use `pcap_next_ex()`, which *does* distinguish between errors and "no packets arrived within the timeout interval".

Comment: This was exactly my problem "read time out start before any packets arrive".

Comment: I changed the to_ms in the pcap_open_live from 1 to 100. Now, I receive all I want.

In fact, at the beginning I used pcap_next_ex and I also received 2 packets. I thought the problem came from the non-blocking mode. That's why I tried to use pcap_next. Now, I changed my code back to pcap_next_ex with a to_ms of 100 and it works.
Thanks

Comment: "I thought the problem came from the non-blocking mode."  Non-blocking mode is an issue only if you turn it on with `pcap_setnonblock()`; it's off by default.  Non-blocking mode is *not* a reason to use `pcap_next()`; `pcap_next_ex()`, `pcap_loop()`, and `pcap_dispatch()` all handle non-blocking mode better than `pcap_next()`.

Comment: "I changed the to_ms in the pcap_open_live from 1 to 100. Now, I receive all I want."  Except when you don't.  1 millisecond is a small timeout - tcpdump uses 1 second and Wireshark uses 250 milliseconds - so a bigger timeout is probably what you want.  However, if traffic gets slow, you will still run the risk of `pcap_next()` returning NULL, so you still should always use `pcap_next_ex()` and *NOT* stop capturing if you get a timeout.